# Dell u2713hm Display on time

Tags: display

I've just bought an used DELL U2713HM monitor and I want to know if it's possible to find out the display on time of the mentioned monitor?
By on time, I mean how many hours/minutes has the display been turned on for.

Thank you!

Comment: Reading it again it seems you want to know how many hours the display as been turned on?  If thats the case thats unlikely something the monitor keeps track of.

Comment: Yes exactly - I know that this feature exists on other Dell monitors - so I hoped this one has this feature too. I'll ask the Dell support and post the result here...

Answer (score 2):

**With the U2711** (I imagine it's similar):

- Power off
- Hold down the menu and brightness buttons (2nd and 4th down of the 5 no-touch buttons)
- Power on- requires holding the power button for a couple of seconds *instead of the usual light up/down waterfall all buttons will light at once and stay on*
- Press the preset modes button (top) and the boring blue diagnostic panel will come up

**Note** the monitor stays in this mode (top button bringing up diagnostics) until you re-power cycle.  While time on is a tracked metric, there's also a reset feature.

**For a U2312HM:**

- Power Off
- Hold down the preset mode and brightness buttons (1st and 2nd down from the top)
- Power on- power led will flash blue/orange
- Press the preset modes button (top) for the good ol' diagnostic panel

Comment: I tested it, it is the last description, like with the U2312: Dell u2713hm turn off
press 1st and 2nd button (from above)
turn on
press 1st button again

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, useful stuff, and here's my contribution...

Dell U2415 / U2515H (maybe others)

1) Power off

2) Hold/cover the 2 left-most buttons

3) Power on

4) Press left-most button for service menu

Comment: Why are you writing 3 separate answers? Please combine them into one answer.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Dell "BID" (built-in diagnostics)

U2410/U2413
Cover/hold buttons 1 and 4 (from the top) for 3 seconds.
Then use button 4 to cycle thru the test screens.

U2415/U2515H
Cover/hold the outer buttons (the left-most button and the right-most button).
Then use the right-most button to cycle thru solid color screens.

You can do this at anytime, don't need to power on/off.

Comment: Why are you writing 3 separate answers? Please combine them into one answer.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Dell U2410/U2413

1) Power off

2) Hold/cover buttons 2 and 4 (from the top)

3) Power on (all button lights will stay lit)

4) Press button 1 (from the top)

Comment: Why are you writing 3 separate answers? Please combine them into one answer.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.